# Better way to convert NSArray of NSNumbers to array of NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` consisting of `NSNumbers` and I want to convert this to an `NSArray` of `NSStrings`, by getting the `stringValue` of each `NSNumber` in the first array.

The method that comes to my mind is iterating each value in the first one, getting its string value and adding it into another array. But there should be a more elegant solution for this. Do you know one?

Comment: I think that your solution is most elegant :-) Because it simple and clear

Comment: If you're making more than a passing effort to find a better solution than 3 lines of code that performs optimally, then you have too much free time.

Comment: @morningstar: :) i dont have that much time actually the situation is the opposite, but sometimes frameworks provide awesome methods that you'd regret not knowing them.i like to find out those if there are any.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`NSArray` implements the [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cat/NSKeyValueCoding) method [`valueForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCIBCDJ) in such a way that it returns a new array. The new array contains the results of asking each object in the original array for the specified value. In this case, `NSNumber` has its `stringValue`, so all you have to do is:

```
NSArray * b = [a valueForKey:@"stringValue"];
```

Plain old fast enumeration (or `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`) wouldn't be a terrible solution, though. `NSArray`'s implementation of `valueForKey:` most likely uses a `for` loop internally, and that would be pretty readily understood by anyone who reads it later.

Comment: Wow, does it really? It does seem abusive but it is also awesome.

Comment: Not abusive — quite idiomatic IMO. The stringValue is a valid attribute of the NSNumber class, and NSArray's valueForKey: is intentionally designed to allow transforming an array this way. This is exactly how I would write it, for whatever that's worth.

Comment: I didn't expect it to, honestly. @jbat100

Comment: @Chuck: Well, your opinion's worth a fair bit as far as I'm concerned. I appreciate the confirmation.

Comment: +1 for the straightforward, correct approach using NSArray's `valueForKey:`.   -1 for the eight other ugly lines of code (which are overly complicated, unclear, and, for some cases, buggy).

Comment: @Nikolai: What's the bug? That it fails if an invalid key is passed? The real `valueForKey:` does too.

Comment: I'd call it mildly abusive only because `stringValue` isn't declared as a property, but as a no-parameter method. You could probably make an object with a method `-(NSNull *)printSelf { NSLog(@"%@", self.description); return [NSNull null]; }` and then use `[myArray valueForKey:@"printSelf"]` to print an array of them, but that doesn't make it right.

Comment: According to the documentation: "valueForKey:
Returns an array containing the results of invoking valueForKey: using key on each of the array's objects." So it doesn't work exactly like your code, but in this case similar. They would also probably use initWithCapacity and I hope for the sake of performance they don't do the copy; maybe there is some clever possibly secret-sauce way to make it immutable without doing a copy.

Comment: @morningstar: Key-Value Coding predates declared properties by many years. There is no documented requirement or even suggestion that the value should be a declared property. The alternative situation you present is indeed a misuse of KVC, but that's because it violates the semantics of an attribute. You could do the same thing with a declared property.

Comment: @Josh Caswell: First and foremost, overriding `valueForKey:` on some arbitrary class seems like a **very** bad idea that will most definitely lead to bugs when using this class's objects in any other context. You basically break that class's KVC compliance.

Comment: @Josh Caswell: Another issue is the the message sent to each of the array's elements. While that might work for `stringValue`, it does not work for methods that return structs or pods. Also, BOOL properties might be named using the "is" prefix (`isHidden` <-> `hidden`). Properties can announce this (`getter=isHidden`) and KVC will take this into account. So why not use `valueForKey:` in your loop? That would solve both of these problems.

Comment: @Josh Caswell: Other things are relatively minor, but led me to call your code ugly (the needless copy to make the result immutable, the bad type `id *`, ...)

Comment: @Josh Caswell: But again, your first proposal of using `valueForKey:` is absolutely right and the best solution to this problem, so: +1 -1 = ±0

Comment: @Nikolai: Oh! I understand your objection now! I was absolutely not suggesting using that code verbatim (especially not overriding `valueForKey:`!) and I will edit to make that completely clear. I was only trying to say that `NSArray`'s implementation of `valueForKey:` most likely uses a `for` loop, and therefore it would be a perfectly acceptable solution for davsan to do so as well. Your point about using `valueForKey:` on each object in the enumeration is well-taken -- the real `-[NSArray valueForKey:]` seems to do the same.

Comment: @Nikolai: Ack, `id *`, an embarrassing slip of the keyboard. I appreciate the critique!

Comment: @Josh Caswell: Sorry for sounding overly critic before. +1 for your modifications.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe: No need. I really do appreciate the critique.