# convert NSArray of NSString(s) to NSArray of NSMutableString(s)

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

How to do that without having to "scroll" the entire given array with a "for" loop?

Comment: What's wrong with the for loop?

Comment: What are you trying to do?   Converting an array of strings into an array of mutable strings seems a bit odd.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Better way to convert NSArray of NSNumbers to NSArray of NSStrings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119043/better-way-to-convert-nsarray-of-nsnumbers-to-nsarray-of-nsstrings). Use the method given in my answer there, passing `mutableCopy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Since nobody seems to agree with my comment that this is a duplicate of [Better way to convert NSArray of NSNumbers to array of NSStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119043/better-way-to-convert-nsarray-of-nsnumbers-to-nsarray-of-nsstrings), here's the same answer again:</sub>

```
NSArray * arrayOfMutableStrings = [arrayOfStrings valueForKey:@"mutableCopy"];
```

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCIBCDJ):

> `valueForKey:`
>   Returns an array containing the results of invoking
>   `valueForKey:` using `key` on each of the array's objects.
>
> `- (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key`
>
> **Parameters**
>   `key` The key to retrieve.
>
> **Return Value**
>   The value of the retrieved key.
>
> **Discussion**
>   The returned array contains `NSNull` elements for each object that returns `nil`.

Comment: I added the description from the docs, I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 4):

The best I can come up with is:

```
NSMutableArray *replacementArray = [NSMutableArray array];

[originalArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:
     ^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
     {
          [replacementArray addObject:[[obj mutableCopy] autorelease]];
     }
];
```

Which more or less just tells the `originalArray` to construct the for loop for you. And if anything it's more work than:

```
NSMutableArray *replacementArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for(id obj in originalArray)
   [replacementArray addObject:[[obj mutableCopy] autorelease]];
```

Comment: @bbum: I'd expect you to be quite right. I should have been explicit in my meaning: it's more typing work than using a for loop. Being unable to think of a reason why the author of the question seems so against the idea of a for loop I took it to be motivated by excess syntax.

Comment: The reason is simple: think about the extreme difference (in terms of performance) whether you use "filteredArrayUsingPredicate:" instead of a "for" loop in order to filter an array with thousands of items in it... I was looking for a faster way for that conversion too   :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a dictionary method on NSArray to be able to write cleaner functional code

```
-(NSArray *)arrayByPerformingBlock:(id (^)(id))performBlock 
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id element in self)
         [array addObject:performBlock(element)];
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
}
```

usage:

```
arrayWithStrings = [arrayWithStrings arrayByPerformingBlock:^id(id element) {return [[element mutableCopy] autorelease];}];
```

This was inspired by list comprehensions I know from Python. I also wrote versions of this methods with testing. See my [arraytools](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/arraytools/blob/master/arraytools/NSArray+FunctionalTools.m).