# Find NSManagedObjects from an NSArray that share a property

Tags: ios, objective-c, compare, nsmanagedobject

I have a fairly large number of NSManagedObjects in an NSArray and need to check whether do any of them have the same value for a property. The obvious way is nested for loops however it will take ages to go through all of them as there are about a 1000 objects in the array.

```
for (NSManagedObject *object in array) {
    for (NSManagedObject *secondObject in array {
        if ([[object valueForKey:@"key"] isEqualTo:[secondObject valueForKey:@"key"]] &&
           object != secondObject) {
            NSLog(@"Sharing a property");
        }
    }
}
```

Any better way to do this? If there are 1000 objects that accounts to 1 000 000 comparisons, that might take some time.

Comment: Do you only need to check if a duplicate value occurs, or do you also need to know *which objects* share the value?

Comment: Also which objects share the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the array according to the values of that property.
Then a single loop over
the array is sufficient to find objects sharing the same value of the property.

Comment: Just to clarify, that would be sort by @"key" and then check if two in a row are the same with a for loop right?

Comment: @DenisBalko: Yes, that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: All great answer but this one seems to be the most simple one so will probably go with it.

Comment: Agree, this is the best answer if your attribute has a linear order relation.

Answer (score 4):

You could use an `NSDictionary`. Each entry would be made from the following pair:

- `key` would be equal to the selected `NSManagedObject`s attribute
- `value` would be an `NSArray` of `NSManagedObject`s, that share this attribute's value

Answer (score 3):

Get [the list of key values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8119126/603977) for the objects in the array, then turn that into a [set](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSSet). If the size of the set is the same as that of the original array, there are no matches.

If you need to know *which* objects match, use a dictionary to create a multiset -- each key has an array of the objects as its value.

[Creating your own keyed set class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15281296/603977) is also an option.